# how to query multiple table using linq

Tags: c#, linq

i am new to linq and got stuck in a scenario which is, say i have a "Student" table with id(pk) and name, and a "Address" table with id(pk), address, studId(fk), city and city table with city id(pk) and city name. now the student can have multiple addresses in "Address" table, i want to get result of all student with multiple city(should be an array) name as one of the property of student entity. like in student object as id,name,address,city[](array of cities).

Answer (score 0):

`Student.addresses = Address.Where(x => x.studId == Student.id).toList();`

This is more or less what you want to do, query your address table where you match on student id you can then cycle through your addresses and pick out the cities, this will also give you more information.

Comment: Thanks ! below answer suited my scenario completely.

Answer (score 0):

```
var students=db.Students.Select(s=>new {
  s.id,
  s.name,
  s.Addresses,
  Cities=s.Addresses.Select(a=>a.City.Name).ToList()
});
```

Of course, you could just select the students...

```
var students=db.Students
  .Include(s=>a.Addresses)
  .Include(s=>a.Addresses.City);
```

Then if you need to know what cities the student is in, it'd be like:

```
foreach(var student in students)
  Console.WriteLine("{0} lives in {1}",
    student.Name,
    String.Join(", ",student.Addresses.Select(a=>a.City.Name)));
```

The above assumes you are using EntityFramework and have your navigation properties set up correctly.